# Continuity of $U:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, inequality, continuity

Let $\Omega \in \mathbb{R^n}$, suppose we have a function $ U \in \mathcal{C}({\Omega})$ i.e $U:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Let $x_1 \in \Omega$
and suppose $\exists M \gt 0$ s.t $U(x_1) \lt M$. Then Why **by continuity of $U$ at $x_1$, there exists $\delta \gt 0$ s.t $U \lt M$ on $B(x_1,\delta)$?**

Can I please have a proof or explanation?

Comment: $U^{-1}(-\infty,M)$ is an open set containing $x_1$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry I didnt get your point, can you explain how did we find $\delta \gt 0$ s.t $u \lt M$ on $B(x_1,\delta)$?

Comment: Try setting $\varepsilon=\frac{M-U(x_1)}{2}$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Can you please solve it, cz I tried with no result? And Sorry I have another question of the definition of an open set $O$: $\forall x \in O \exists \delta \gt 0$ s.t $B(x,r) \subset O$, shall $B(x,r)$ be open or it may be closed?

Answer (score 0):

$O:=U^{-1}[(-\infty, M)]$ is an open subset of $\Omega$ (by continity of $U$) with $x_1 \in O$ by definition. As $O$ is open, $x_1$ is an interior point of $O$ so there is some $\delta>0$ so that

$$B(x_1, \delta) \cap \Omega \subseteq O= U^{-1}[(-\infty, M)] \text{ so: } \forall x \in \Omega: d(x,x_1) < \delta \to U(x) < M$$

That last condition is what's meant by "$U < M$ on $B(x_1, \delta)$".

If $\Omega$ is open, we can also ensure that $B(x_1, \delta) \subseteq \Omega$ as well, because then $x_1$ is an interior point of $\Omega$ as well.

Comment: Sry but I have a general question: the definition of $O$ as an open set is: $\forall$ $x \in O$, $\exists \delta \gt 0$ s.t $B(x,\delta) \subset O$. Regarding $B(x,\delta)$, can we choose it closed, or it must be open? Thank you.

Comment: You could choose it to be an open ball so with $\le$ or an open one with $<$. They are equivalent. @sara An open ball with radius $\delta$ contains a closed one of radius $0 < \delta' < \delta$ so if you want a closed one, pick that.

Comment: so as a conclusion, to prove $O$ is open, we can either prove that it contains a closed ball , or an open ball?

Comment: but why we can choose both, and we are not restricted to only one ball, as if open (or closed only). Why we can take both with no problem?

Comment: @sara As I explained: a set is open iff we can find for each of its points an open ball inside it iff we can find for each of its balls a closed ball inside it.

Comment: okay, because if we found closed ball, so it already contains an open one of same radius, so it's true. And if it contains an open ball, we can find a smaller radius than $\delta$, so that it contains a closed ball, so both are true. Isnt it?

Comment: @sara exactly. That’s what I meant.

Comment: Sorry but regarding my question, can we then say that, and after talking on a ball, if I have $u$ continuous on $\Omega$,and $\exists M>0$ s.t $u \lt M$ in $\Omega$, so $\exists x \in \Omega$ (which is close to the boundary) s.t $u(x) \lt M$. So, and because $u$ is continuous, $\exists r \gt 0$ s.t $u \lt M$ on $B(x,r)$ and so at $\partial{\Omega}$. As a conclusion: I I have a continuous function $u$ s.t $u \lt M$ in $\Omega$, then $u \lt M$ at $\partial{\Omega}$?

Comment: Maybe you can may see my last question in my page, and hopefully you answer me there. Thank you.